# What is the best separation concepts for Android. How to separate packages in the best way

Tags: android, package

How to separate different packages for android app for this target:

- I have several views, on which we will edit and show some data.
- Also I have `REST service`.

How to separate packages in the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have a family of products, I like to make a "common core" library of shared features.  There are several examples of how to create/use a "android library" - see the documentation "Managing Projects From Eclipse w/ADT" has a section "Setting up a Library Project"

Also, there is a sample application w/the SDK which illustrates library usage.  See "TicTacToeLib" and "TicTacToeMain"

Answer (score 0):

Separe package based on android component, Activity, contentProvider, database, broadcast, ui for customcomponent .... see the Google open sources projects http://code.google.com/p/libs-for-android/